# Cobertura coverage for single file with maven

Tags: maven-2, junit, cobertura

How do you invoke the cobertura maven plugin when running unit tests for a single file so that you can get coverage reports for just that file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest exlcuding all other files from instrumentation.

Comment: Good idea. Thanks for that. is it possible to view the report without using the maven site plugin to generate a site?

Comment: I'm not really the maven expert :) But the cobertura:cobertura target seems to generate a report (http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/cobertura-mojo.html). Basically you always need to have some kind of report, because the cobertura.ser file is not really human.readable.